# Conway's Game of Life Method

Tags: java, conways-game-of-life

I am trying to build a Conway's Game of Life program for my CS class and I am stuck on one of the methods. Here is what i have so far:

```
public class GameOfLifeFunctions {
    public static void toggleCell(int row, int col, int[][] board) {
        // TODO: This next line crashes the program, so delete it when you start coding
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("DELETE THIS LINE WHEN YOU START CODING");
        board[row][col]=board[row][col]==0?1:0;
    }

    public static void resetCells(int[][] board) {
        // TODO: This next line crashes the program, so delete it when you start coding
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("DELETE THIS LINE WHEN YOU START CODING");
        for (int j=0; j<board.length; j++) {
            for (int i=0; i<board.length; i++) {
                board[j][i]=0;
            }
        }
    }

    public static int[][] copyCells(int[][] board) {
        int[][] copy=new int[board.length][board[0].length];

        // TODO: This next line crashes the program, so delete it when you start coding
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("DELETE THIS LINE WHEN YOU START CODING");
        for (int j=0; j<board.length; j++) {
            for (int i=0; i<board.length; i++) {
                copy[j][i]=board[j][i];
            }            
        }
        return copy;
    }

    public static int getNumLiveNeighbors(int[][] cells, int row, int col) {
        int h=cells.length;
        int w=cells[0].length;
        int count=0;

        // TODO: This next line crashes the program, so delete it when you start coding
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("DELETE THIS LINE WHEN YOU START CODING");  
        for (int j=row-1; j<=row+1; j++) {
            for (int i=col-1; i<=col+1; i++) {
                //Something broken in this if statement
                //OutOfBounds problem
                if (j==row && i==col) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (j<0 || j>h-1 || 1<0 || i>w-1) {
                    ;
                }       
                else if (cells[j][i]==1) {
                    count++;
                }                
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static int[][] calcualteNextGeneration(int[][] cells) {
        // TODO: Calculate the next generation by calling getNumLiveNeighbors for each
        // cell in the grid. Put the results of the new generation into the 2D array result.
        int[][] result=new int[cells.length][cells[0].length];
        int living;

        // TODO: This next line crashes the program, so delete it when you start coding
        for (int j; j<cells.length; j++) {
            for (int i; i<cells[0].length; i++) {

            }
        }
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("DELETE THIS LINE WHEN YOU START CODING");
    }
```

I am stuck on the `getNumLiveNeighbors` method. If you could help me out and explain that would be great!

Comment: Select your code and press  CTL +K

Comment: I am trying to return the number of each cells neighbor to tell if it is alive (bool=1) or dead (bool=0). I want to calculate for the next generation and getting to work up the method is where I am having the trouble. I'm sorry that my question is vague.

Answer (score 1):

In `if (j<0 || j>h-1 || 1<0 || i>w-1)` I think you mean `i<0` as the third test instead of `1<0`.